# How to download GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz now need to add access code

Tags: geoip, maxmind

Plugin I have uses this url which no longer works as need a license key obviously now
https://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb.gz

I have tried this url (Note: I have removed my license key from the below) but it doesn't work any ideas

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download_by_token?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country&license_key={LICENSE KEY HERE}&suffix=mmdb.gz

Comment: https://github.com/wp-statistics/GeoLite2-City

Answer (score 20):

I think instead of going through the lengthy registration process, one should download it from [this github repo](https://github.com/P3TERX/GeoLite.mmdb).
At the time of this writing, this repo was very recent.

Comment: A helpful link. Thank you @sa-mustafa.

Comment: Still actual, updated two days ago. Thank's!

Comment: Still up to date and working in 06-2023 !

Comment: Still works  very good.

Comment: Not working properly, I tested it

Answer (score 7):

You will need a (free) license key. You can use this bash 1 liner with `YOUR_LICENSE_KEY`

```sh
curl "https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz" -o GeoLite2-Country.tar.gz \
  && tar -xzvf GeoLite2-Country.tar.gz \
  && mkdir -p /var/opt/maxmind/ \
  && mv GeoLite2-Country_*/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb /var/opt/maxmind/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
```

Comment: Did you mean to include (your?) license key in that example?

Comment: It was only an (invalid) sample, answer clarified to use a variable. Thanks.

Comment: But how can we generate a license key ? On the GeoIP2Lite wabesite, we need to login to create license key... But I'm not working for an entreprise !

Answer (score 1):

Permalinks for GeoLite2 Country×

Below are permalinks that you can use to download the database.

Remember to replace **YOUR_LICENSE_KEY**.

## Database URL

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz

## SHA256 URL

https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=tar.gz.sha256

Answer (score 0):

I read this information (https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoipupdate/).
You can try this https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-City&license_key={LICENSE KEY HERE}&suffix=tar.gz